# Add item to @Html.DropDownList with option value and set default selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am rendering a select list in my view like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectCategory", (SelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "All")
```

I populate it like so:

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
```

That renders:

```
<select id="SelectCategory" name="SelectCategory">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="44">T-Shirts</option>
</select>
```

Issues:

1) The option value for `All` is empty, how can I put my value there, say `0` ?

2) How can I set a default selected value in `@Html.DropDownList` ?

Comment: You need to show how you populate your SelectList from your controller.

Comment: @Yanga just did, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your select "by hands"

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in optionList)
{
    if(myCondition)
    {
        <option value="@item.Value" selected="selected">@item.Text</option> 
    }
    else 
    {
         <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
} 
</select>
```

or using Linq in the view

```
var list = optionsList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value, Selected = myCondition });
```

then you could used that list in one of the Html.DropdownList
Here is the full example

```
int catId = // Gets the catId to select somehow
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options = optionsList
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { 
         Text = x.Text, 
         Value = x.Value, 
         Selected = x.Value == catId
     }); // catId
```

And then you use it like this :

```
 @Html.DropdownList("id-of-the-dropdown", options);
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to do it with @Html.DropDownList if possible.

Comment: An other option could be to build your list options in the view using Linq

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer if @Html.DropDownList cant handle this.

Comment: A good practice is to keep that kind of code out of your controllers as much as possible so that if for any reason you need to change the UI (to show radio buttons instead of a dropdownlist for example), you'll only have to edit the view.

Comment: I wrote how I populate the select, can you give a full example based on that and linq in your last edit? And `myCondition` is an int catId parameter that comes via GET. And I am not sure I can use DropDownListFor because I am already using a model in that view.

Comment: @frc
I added the code on how to use the linq query and use the result with the helper you wanted. Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd parameter of the `DropDownList()` method adds a 'label' option with a `null` value. Typically the option text is something like "Please select" and its purpose is to force a user to make a valid selection. If the label option is selected, a `null` value is submitted and `ModelState` is invalid (assuming the property your binding to is required).

If you want an additional option with `<option value="0">All</option>`, then you need to generate that in the `SelectList` you pas to the view, for example

```
List<SelectListItem> categories = db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(), // assumes Id is not already typeof string
    Text = x.Name
}).ToList();
categories.Insert(0, new SelectListItem(){ Value = "0", Text = "All" }) // Or .Add() to add as the last option
ViewBag.Categories = categories;
```

and in the view (note remove the 3rd parameter is you do not want the label option)

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectCategory", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories, "Please select")
```

In order to 'select' an option initially, you need to set the value of the property your binding to before you pass the model to the view, so if the value of property `SelectCategory` is `"0"`, the the "All" option will be selected when the view is first displayed. If its `"44"`, then the "T-Shirts" option will be selected. If the value of `SelectCategory` does not match one of the option values, or is `null`, then the first option will be selected (because soemthing has to be)

Comment: This look great, will try it tomorrow, just one thing seems to be missing from my Q: how do I set the default value? I am getting an id in my POST action and I would use that to select an option.

Comment: See the last paragraph of the answer. If your set the value of property `SelectCategory = 0` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, then the option matching that value (`"All"`) will be selected - that's how model binding works - its binds to the value of your property. I'm not sure what your mean by _I am getting an id in my POST action and I would use that to select an option_ (what does the POST method have to do with it?)

Comment: I am sorry it is late, I meant GET, I just meant I get a value there I can use. OK got it, will test it out first thing.